# Increase/decrease DIV and PROGRESSBAR Value CSS/JS - positioning elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I want to create simple donation option using CSS/JS and HTML.
I have this photo of how it supposed to look like:
[image: I want to achieve something like this using JS/CSS/HTML]

Plus button should increase donation, while it's increasing, the progressbar should be changing too. Same with minus button with decreasing value.
I thought that it would be easier, but I have problems on the beginning,
The main problem for me is positioning elements, so I would apprecieate if someone give me instructions or send me to a good tutorial about positioning. I am total beginner.

Here's where I stuck for now:

```js
var donate = parseInt(document.getElementById(donate_nr).innerHTML);

function increaseDonate() {
  if (donate < 750) {
    donate += 10;
    document.getElementById("donate_nr").innerHTML = donate;
  } else document.getElementById("donate_nr").innerHTML = donate + "Thank you, that's the maximum you can donate.";
}

function decreaseDonate() {
  if (donate > 0) {
    donate -= 10;
    document.getElementById("donate_nr").innerHTML = donate;
  }
}
```

```css
.minButton {
    background: #17f8b2;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    font-family: 'coc';
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 33px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #907d10;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.plusButton {
    background: #17f8b2;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    font-family: 'coc';
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 33px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #907d10;
}

.col1{
    float:left;
    width: 10%;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    position:f
}

.col3{
    float:right;
    width:10%;
}

.divContainer{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007ead 0%,#006188 100%);
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.donateValue{
        text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 3.6em;
        padding: 17px 20px 10px 80px;
    font-family: 'coc';
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Your Donation:
</h1>
<br>
<div class=columnWrapper>
<div class="col1">
<div class="minButton" onclick="decreaseDonate()">-</div></div>

<div class="col2">
    <div class="divContainer">
        <div id="donate_nr" class="donateValue">10
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col3">
<div class="plusButton" onclick="increaseDonate()">+</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to wrap `getElementById(donate_nr)` in quotes. Do it like this - `parseInt(document.getElementById('donate_nr').innerHTML);` Also, you forgot to include the html element for the progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `float` you can use `flex` for the layout you can find a complete tutorial on [mdn flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```js
var donate = parseInt(document.getElementById('donate_nr').innerHTML);

function increaseDonate() {
  if (donate < 750) {
    donate += 10;
    document.getElementById("donate_nr").innerHTML = donate;
  } else document.getElementById("donate_nr").innerHTML = donate + "Thank you, that's the maximum you can donate.";
}

function decreaseDonate() {
  if (donate > 0) {
    donate -= 10;
    document.getElementById("donate_nr").innerHTML = donate;
  }
}
```

```css
.minButton {
    background: #17f8b2;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    font-family: 'coc';
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 33px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #907d10;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.plusButton {
    background: #17f8b2;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    font-family: 'coc';
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 45px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #907d10;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.columnWrapper{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.col1{
    width: 10%;
    padding:5px
}
.col2{
    width:90%;
}
.col3{
    width:10%;
    padding:5px
}

.divContainer{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007ead 0%,#006188 100%);
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.donateValue{
        text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 3.6em;
        padding: 17px 20px 10px 80px;
    font-family: 'coc';
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Your Donation:
</h1>
<br>
<div class=columnWrapper>
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="minButton" onclick="decreaseDonate()">-</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
      <div class="divContainer">
          <div id="donate_nr" class="donateValue">10
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
    <div class="plusButton" onclick="increaseDonate()">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an extra div for the progress bar which has `position: absolute` within your `divContainer`, and you will need to give this a `position: relative` value to allow the child to be absolutely positioned within it. Then you can add a line of code to your JS functions to give the progress bar a percentage width whenever the donation amount changes.

```
<div class="divContainer">
  <div id="donate_nr" class="donateValue">10</div>
  <div class="progressBar"></div>
</div>

// CSS:
.divContainer {
  position: relative;
  // etc.
}

.progressBar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

// JS:
// In both `increaseDonate()` and `decreaseDonate()`, call this at the end
// to set the width of the progress bar by percentage:
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progressBar');
progressBar.style.width = `${donate / 750 * 100}%;`
```